# Python - Perform a FIFO operation on data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in Pandas that looks like this.

```
| DAY | IN  | OUT |
|-----|-----|-----|
|   1 | 100 |  50 |
|   2 |  20 |  60 |
|   3 |  10 |   5 |
|   4 |   5 |  15 |
```

This represents the day an item went into a queue, and how many came out of the queue. When things go into the queue, I don't really have a way of tracking them so I assume that they are processed in order and you have a FIFO (first in, first out) type operation.

What I want to do is perform a FIFO operation so I can see what how many days the operation took. So as an example...

```
| DAY | IN  | OUT |   1 |   2 |   3 |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|   1 | 100 |  50 |  50 |   0 |   0 |
|   2 |  20 |  60 |  10 |  50 |   0 |
|   3 |  10 |   5 |   0 |   5 |   0 |
|   4 |   5 |  15 |   0 |  10 |   5 |
```

The last 3 columns I appended represent how many came out of the process in how many days. So said verbally...

- On day 1, 100 went in and 50 came out. Therefore, 50 were processed in 1 day and 50 remained in queue.
- On day 2, 20 went in and 60 came out. Therefore, the prior queue of 50 was exhausted and those took 2 days. The remaining 10 that came out completed in 1 day. 10 remained in queue.
- On day 3, 10 went in and 5 came out. Therefore, the prior queue of 10 was reduced to 5. Those 5 that came out were competed in 2 days. 15 remained in queue.
- On day 4, 5 went in and 15 came out. Therefore, the prior queue of 15 was exhausted. 5 took 3 days to complete and 10 took 2 days. 5 remained in queue.
- etc.

Anyone have some code (or pseudocode) to do this in a pythonic way, preferably using Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

I've coded exactly what you need, it will return the result you expect (I've added some rows to verify it). If you want more than 3 days of latence, you can add the `Supply` columns as well (it's easy to understand what to do, it is always the same thing) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Day'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
df['In'] = [100, 20, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10]
df['Out'] = [50, 60, 5, 15, 5, 0, 20]

df['Supply'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['In']-row['Out'], axis=1)
df['Supply'] = df['Supply'].cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)
df['1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Out'] - row['Supply'] if row['Supply'] < row['Out'] else 0, axis=1)
df['Supply-2'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Supply'] - row['Out'] + row['1'], axis=1)
df['Supply-2'] = df['Supply-2'].shift(1).fillna(0)
df['2'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Out'] - row['1'] - row['Supply-2'], axis=1)
df['3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Out'] - row['1'] - row['2'], axis=1)

print(df[['Day', 'In', 'Out', '1', '2', '3']])
```

Returns :

```
   Day   In  Out     1     2     3
0    1  100   50  50.0   0.0   0.0
1    2   20   60  10.0  50.0   0.0
2    3   10    5   0.0   5.0   0.0
3    4    5   15   0.0  10.0   5.0
4    5   10    5   0.0   5.0   0.0
5    6   10    0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6    7   10   20   0.0  10.0  10.0
```

**Explanations** : Everything is about `Supply` which is the amount of `In` which has not been `Out`. In order to add the temporal information (because `Supply` does not know the age of the `In`), we add the `Supply-2` column, which quantify the amount of `Supply` which has been here for 2 days. It is only maths after, to know the amount of the 3 last columns.

See ya !